# Scaling small objects using THREE.TransformControls

Tags: three.js

I have a simple editor for 3D models using three.js.

This is my camera:

```
new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
```

And this is my mesh's geometry:

```
new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
```

I'm using [`THREE.TransformControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_transform) to scale the mesh.

Scaling works perfectly fine when meshes have units ~ 100, but when an object is between 0 and 1, scaling is *very* slow. With *slow*, I mean that when you drag the scale slider half the canvas size, the mesh increases or decreases only a few percentages in size. I don't have this problem with other TransformControls modes.

[JSFiddle demonstrating slow scaling](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm19u6dj/1)

I could switch to bigger units, but I'd like to know if this can be solved without having to replace all units throughout my app code.

So my question: **In THREE.TransformControls, is there a way to translate dragging to scaling in a more natural way while dealing with small units?**

Comment: Your fiddle didn't show up for me; I had to change it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm19u6dj/1/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TransformControls` scales the distance of the mouse movement by a seemingly arbitrary amount (`1/50`) within the `onMouseMove` function:

```
        } else if (_mode == "scale") {

            point.sub(offset);
            point.multiply(parentScale);

            if (scope.space == "local") {

                if (scope.axis == "XYZ") {

                    scale = 1 + ((point.y) / 50);

                    scope.object.scale.x = oldScale.x * scale;
                    scope.object.scale.y = oldScale.y * scale;
                    scope.object.scale.z = oldScale.z * scale;

                } else {

                    point.applyMatrix4(tempMatrix.getInverse(worldRotationMatrix));

                    if (scope.axis == "X") scope.object.scale.x = oldScale.x * (1 + point.x / 50);
                    if (scope.axis == "Y") scope.object.scale.y = oldScale.y * (1 + point.y / 50);
                    if (scope.axis == "Z") scope.object.scale.z = oldScale.z * (1 + point.z / 50);

                }

            }

        }
```

This parameter (`50`) effectively controls the "speed" at which the object is scaled (compared to how far the mouse is dragged). You're going to need to patch `TransformControls` in order to change it; I got it to work better by changing `50` to something smaller, like `1`.

```
        } else if (_mode == "scale") {

            point.sub(offset);
            point.multiply(parentScale);

            // by default this is 50; set it to smaller values if you're using smaller units
            scaleSpeed = 1;

            if (scope.space == "local") {

                if (scope.axis == "XYZ") {

                    scale = 1 + ((point.y) / scaleSpeed);

                    scope.object.scale.x = oldScale.x * scale;
                    scope.object.scale.y = oldScale.y * scale;
                    scope.object.scale.z = oldScale.z * scale;

                } else {

                    point.applyMatrix4(tempMatrix.getInverse(worldRotationMatrix));

                    if (scope.axis == "X") scope.object.scale.x = oldScale.x * (1 + point.x / scaleSpeed);
                    if (scope.axis == "Y") scope.object.scale.y = oldScale.y * (1 + point.y / scaleSpeed);
                    if (scope.axis == "Z") scope.object.scale.z = oldScale.z * (1 + point.z / scaleSpeed);

                }

            }

        }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/494uvxfg/ .

three.js r68

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I created an issue for it in the threejs bug tracker: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5489